# Get list of data from a Table based on data in a related table without duplicate

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, foreign-keys, relationship

**Tables in Database:**

1. I have two tables in MySQL `STORES` and `NEW_ARRIVALS`.
2. One has all the store details and other table stores the new arrivals detail if there is any.
3. Both are linked via a column `store_id`.

**What I am trying to do:**

1. List all stores that have an entry for arrival, without showing duplicate stores.

Two SQL queries I tried:

```
SELECT 
        stores.id,
        stores.name 
        new_arrivals.id,
        new_arrivals.title,
        new_arrivals.store_id
FROM 
        stores, 
        new_arrivals
```

The above SQL works but lists multiple stores. For each new arrival in a store, there is a row. I only want one entry per store.

So I tried the below SQL query:

```
SELECT         
       na.id,
       na.is_active,
       na.store_id      
FROM 
       new_arrivals  as na    
group by na.store_id
```

The above query gives unique `store_ids` but I can get info from `stores` table.

I further tried the below with no result:

```
SELECT         
       na.id,
       na.is_active,
       na.store_id      
FROM 
       new_arrivals  as 

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name 
    FROM stores as sl
) As locations

group by na.store_id
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your queries is that you are missing a join condition between the tables. Without it, you are actually generating a Cartesian product of the tables.

This:

```
FROM 
    stores, 
    new_arrivals
```

Should be written:

```
FROM stores
INNER JOIN new_arrivals
    ON new_arrivals.store_id = stores.store_id
```

But even like this, you would still get one row per arrival, which is not what you seem to want. I think you want `exists`:

```
select s.*
from store s
where exists (
    select 1
    from new_arrivals na 
    where na.store_id = s.store_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped in getting a better understanding of whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

This gives only those stores which have an entry in new arrival.

```
SELECT 
        distinct s.id, s.name 
FROM stores s 
INNER JOIN new_arrivals na on na.store_id = s.store_id;
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. It's a neat solution.